# PostgreSQL group order array totally wrong

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

This is the correct ordered array with MySQL:

```
[
  [1330210800000, 1],
  [1330297200000, 6],
  [1330383600000, 10], 
  [1330470000000, 2],
  [1330556400000, 5],
  [1330815600000, 9],
  [1331593200000, 2], 
  [1331852400000, 4],
  [1331938800000, 8],
  [1332111600000, 8],
  [1332198000000, 4], 
  [1332284400000, 8],
  [1332370800000, 3], 
  [1332630000000, 2] 
]
```

But with PostgreSQL the array is:

```
[
  [1330588800000, 5], 
  [1332399600000, 3], 
  [1330848000000, 9], 
  [1330416000000, 10], 
  [1331622000000, 2], 
  [1330329600000, 6], 
  [1330502400000, 2], 
  [1332140400000, 8], 
  [1332313200000, 8], 
  [1330243200000, 1], 
  [1332226800000, 4], 
  [1331967600000, 8], 
  [1332658800000, 2], 
  [1331881200000, 4] 
]
```

The postgreSQL is the order wrong and the dates different and the count of kliks:

This is the query in my controller:

```
@kliks = Klik.count( :group => "DATE( created_at )" )
         .map{|k, v| [(Time.parse(k).to_i * 1000), v] }
```

Comment: Not that my rails knowledge is razor sharp, but if you want things ordered by created_at, don't you need to add `:order => created_at` to your count?

Comment: I will try it :order => 'created_at ASC' just strange that mySQL order it correct. Is the DATE function the same in postgresql?

Comment: @Railsbeginner: Some databases will sort things as a side effect of applying a GROUP BY clause, some won't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't specified any particular order in your query so the database is free to return your results in any order it wants. Apparently MySQL is ordering the results as a side effect of its GROUP BY but PostgreSQL won't necessarily do that. So your first "bug" is just an incorrect assumption on your part. If you want the database to do the sorting then you want something like:

```
Klik.count(:group => 'date(created_at)', :order => :date_created_at)
```

If you throw out the `* 1000` and sort the integer timestamps:

```
1330210800, 1,  MySQL
1330243200, 1,  PostgreSQL

1330297200, 6,  MySQL
1330329600, 6,  PostgreSQL

1330383600, 10, MySQL
1330416000, 10, PostreSQL

...
```

You'll see that they do actually line up quite nicely and the integer timestamps differ by 32400s (AKA 9 hours) or 28800s (AKA 8 hours or 9 hours with a DST adjustment) in each MySQL/PostgreSQL pair. Presumably you're including a time zone (with DST) in one of your conversions while the other is left in UTC.

Comment: Just tried Klik.find(:all, :order => 'created_at ASC').count( :group => "DATE( created_at )").map{|k, v| [(Time.parse(k).to_i * 1000), v] } Got the error undefined map for fixum.

Comment: Also tried: @kliks = Klik.count( :order => 'created_at ASC', :group => "DATE( created_at )").map{|k, v| [(Time.parse(k).to_i * 1000), v] }
 Error:ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (P
GError: ERROR:  column "kliks.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or
be used in an aggregate function
←[35m2012-03-25T18:19:11+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m : SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, D
ATE( created_at ) AS date_created_at FROM "kliks" GROUP BY DATE( created_at ) OR
DER BY created_at ASC):

Comment: it works, where is there some documention about this kind of ordering method you are using?

Comment: @Railsbeginner: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-count

Answer (score 0):

You are really missing the order clause. By default, database servers return groups in "random" order. **The rule is:** when you need to fix the order, always use ORDER BY (in rails its :order).

Comment: Where should the order go? I commented some error in mu is too short answers.

Comment: "Random order" is not correct. "Undefined order" is more accurate.

Comment: That's why the quotes. But I agree.